# Basic Sets and PIE Question

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Question: Suppose $n(S)$ is the number of subset of $S$ and $|S|$ be the number of elements of $S$. If $n(A)+n(B)+n(C)=n(A\cup B\cup C)$ and $|A|=|B|=100$, Find the minimum value of $|A\cap B\cap C|$.

Now, I realise PIE is the only way to go, but I don't know how to handle the intersections of the sets taken two at a time. 
Also, I know that this is a duplicate, but the original on wasn't answered fully. I'd request you o kindly provide a solution before mercilessly closing it off.

Plus, I'm not good at even very basic set theory. If you could recommend a short but good book for set-theory, I'd be much obliged.

Thank you all!

Comment: About good set-theory books, "Introduction to Set Theory" by Hrbacek & Jech is a very nice introduction to (axiomatic) set theory. The nice thing is that it is about axiomatic set theory instead of naive set theory, and it is written with the idea to be readable for students who are unfamiliar with formal logic (contrary to most books on set theory).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $n(S) = 2^{|S|}$.

**Hint:** Hence, what does the first equation translate into?

> $2^{100} + 2^{100} + 2^{|C|} = 2^{|A \cup B \cup C|}$

**Hint:** What are the solutions to this equation?

> $|C| = 101, |A \cup B \cup C| = 102$

**Hint:** $|(A \cup B ) - C| = 1, |(B \cup C ) - A| = 2, |(C \cup A ) - B| = 2$

**Hint:**  $  A \cap B \cap C = A \cup B \cup B  - ((A \cup B ) - C) - ((B \cup C ) - A) - ((C \cup A ) - B)$

> Hence $|A \cap B \cap C | \geq 102 - 1 - 2 - 2 = 97$.

**Hint:** Can equality hold?

> Yes.

Comment: I got what you're trying to say sir. Thanks! Could you give me some resources to review elementary set theory fast? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1.**

Write $c=|C|$ and $x=|A\cup B\cup C|$ (so $c\leq x$), then we have to solve a following equation in nonnegative integers:

$$ 2^{101}+2^c = 2^x\implies 2^c(2^{x-c}-1)= 2^{101}$$

so $$2^{x-c}-1= 2^{101-c}\implies 1=2^{x-c}-2^{101-c}$$

so $x-c>101-c$ and thus $x\geq 102$. Now $$2^{101-c}(2^{x-101}-1) =1\implies 1=2^{101-c}\wedge 2^{x-101}=2$$

So $c=101$ and $x-101=1 \implies x=102$

---

**Part 2:**

Now, by PIE we have \begin{align}|A\cap B| &=|A|+|B|- |A\cup B| \\
&\geq 200-|A\cup B \cup C| \\
&= 98\end{align}

Name $D= A\cap B$. Then clearly $C\cup D \subseteq A\cup B \cup C$ so \begin{align}|C\cap D| &=|C|+|D|- |C\cup D| \\
&\geq 101+98-|A\cup B \cup C| \\
&= 97\end{align}

So $|A\cap B\cap C|\geq 97$.